# MySQL return result if 0 rows returned

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code:

```
$query = "SELECT name, COUNT(message) FROM guestbook_message WHERE name='".$req_user_info['username']."' GROUP BY name"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "Messages posted: ". $row['COUNT(message)'] ."";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Which will show the amount of comments a user has posted.

How do I make it return a value if there is no messages posted from that user? Currently is displays nothing at all. But I want it to show "Messages posted: 0"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the number of results returned in result using [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows).

```
$query = "SELECT name, COUNT(message) FROM guestbook_message WHERE name='".$req_user_info['username']."' GROUP BY name"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "Messages posted: ". $row['COUNT(message)'] ."";
       echo "<br />";
    }
else
    echo "NO Messages posted. <br />";
```

Comment: This gives a warning if the result is 0 rows! PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Messages posted: ". $row['COUNT(message)'] . "";
    echo "<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Messages posted: 0";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mellamokb! I also forgot to put the AND deleted in my WHERE clause. It's been a long day...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$row['COUNT(message)']` with the [tertiary operator](https://www.php.net/ternary):

```
( $row['COUNT(message)'] > 0 ? $row['COUNT(message)'] : 0 )
```

This is basically a compacted `if... else...` statement.